# Erro ao fechar porta serial em c#

Tags: c#, serial

Sou novo em C#. Fiz um programa, que fica lendo continuamente os dados da porta serial e mostrando em um textBox.

Até ai, tudo funciona bem. O problema ocorre quando tento fechar a porta, ele da o seguinte erro

> A operação de E/S foi anulada devido a uma saída de *thread* ou a uma requisição de aplicativo;

Já li várias threads sobre o mesmo assunto, mas ainda não consegui resolver.

Segue abaixo parte do código.

```
public FormRelatorio()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormPrincipal.SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.DataReceived += 
          new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort_DataReceived_RL);
}
```

```
private void SerialPort_DataReceived_RL(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    rxSerialRL = FormPrincipal.SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.ReadLine();
    BeginInvoke(new Fdelegate(recebeSerial), new object[] { rxSerialRL });    
}
```

```
public void recebeSerial(string a)
{
    textBoxTesteMSG.Text = a; 
}
```

Comment: se você só trocar `BeginInvoke(new Fdelegate(recebeSerial), new object[] { rxSerialRL });` por `recebeSerial(rxSerialRL);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Tenta isso e no lugar de `CommPort` coloque o nome de sua classe que endereça a Porta Serial.

```
void CloseComPort()
{

CommPort com=CommPort.Instance;
com.Close();
}
```

Espero que seja o começo da solução de sua necessidade.